# Are there any statistics texts which give both intuition AND justifications for the equations/methods?

Tags: reference-request, statistics

Background:  I took multiple statistics classes in both high school and college, but nothing I learned ever stuck.  The problem is, things like p-tests, the equations for chi-squared/normal distributions, even the standard deviation are always simply presented as fact, without any proof/justification/motivation for why *this* equation/method is the *correct* one.

Often, this is because the books are written for people looking to simply apply statistics rather than truly understand it.  Usually, not even a calculus-background is assumed, despite the underlying equations being calculus-heavy.

*Non-calculus example: [Why is the standard deviation not defined as the average distance from the mean](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4787), when that is the more intuitively obvious definition?  I still don't quite understand the answer to that one...*

I did find some books that *do* go deeply into proofs in my college's mathematics library, but even those were heavy on symbols and light on justifications/motiviations *(as well as real-world examples)*

Does anyone know of any statistics books that not only go over the equations/methods, but explain in detail *why* they are what they are?

Comment: I've recently started a [resource](https://thewindingnumber.blogspot.in/p/contents.html) that seems to answer some of your concerns. You may want to check the "Statistics" course -- it's still *very* incomplete, though.

Answer (score 1):

wackerly et. al., Mathematical statistics. Very good! :)