# A book on statistics similar to Michael Spivak's Calculus

Tags: statistics, reference-request, book-recommendation

I'm looking for an book on statistics that's similar to Michael Spivak's *Calculus*. It should be rigorous, starting with some fundamental axioms and build layers of theorems on top of it, and it should be concise.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2281243/a-good-book-for-introduction-to-mathematical-statistics

Comment: Calculus is structured that way, but statistics isn't. Good statistics  books aren't either.

Comment: Related: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/31655/statistics-for-mathematicians

Comment: The concisest might be Silvey's *Statistical Inference*; if you want a book that covers the prerequisite probability theory, you'll need something longer. There are plenty of books called "mathematical statistics" that do things axiomatically, in definition-theorem-proof style.

Comment: A rule for picking excellent applies does not necessary lead to picking excellent oranges.

Comment: @BruceET: Well, for some people's taste, the best way to serve an orange is to replace it by an apple :)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Spivak's Calculus book, but I have his Calculus on Manifolds book. If they are similar then [this book](https://www.amazon.com/Mathematical-Statistics-Springer-Texts/dp/0387953825/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1517808791&sr=8-1&keywords=mathematical+statistics+jun+shao) is a good rigorous book of a similar style. It isn't so technically demanding that it's unapproachable, but is well written and concise while covering many topics.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the book by [Kiefer](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387964207) which is based on the course he taught at Cornell University. It requires very little prerequisites and builds up the modern theory of statistical inference. I personally think it is a great introductory book on statistical inference.