# Recommended textbooks for statistics

Tags: statistics, reference-request, statistical-inference, descriptive-statistics

I am currently a second year science student double majoring in biochemistry and applied statistics. The stats course im doing this semester (Statistical Theory) is focused on joint probability distributions, moments of univariate distributions, moment generating function, distribution of sample statistics and parameter estimation. We have no recommended textbook for this course (instead my college offers their own notes with tutorial exercises at the end). I wrote my first test for this course and it turns out that the tutorial exercises are extremely easy (and few) in comparison. Can anyone recommend a textbook with practice questions so i can become more confident with anything they might throw my way??

Thank you

Comment: Might be a better fit for https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: duplicates https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6254/recommend-a-statistics-fundamentals-book

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there any statistics texts which give both intuition AND justifications for the equations/methods?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/274883/are-there-any-statistics-texts-which-give-both-intuition-and-justifications-for)

Answer (score 0):

You don't give much of an idea what you are studying, so it's even harder than usual to give well-targeted suggestions. I will mention a couple of books I have used often over the last 10-15 years--in various editions.

> Math. Stat w/ Applications: Wackerly, Mendenhall, Scheaffer. Includes lots of probability at the start. Used copies of older editions should be less expensive and just about as good. Some answers in the back of the book. Student guides may be available for some editions.
>
> Statistical Methods and data analysis: Ott & Longnecker.
> Again, look for older editions. Huge thick book. Stay with the earlier chapters for now. Some answers in the back of the book.

Maybe your college has a library with copies of these books on the shelves so you can take a look before you go online looking for copies to buy. Maybe in the process of that will you will find other books that
you like.

You might also do some targeted searches on this site for various topics causing you trouble. *Sometimes,* you
will find really clear questions with really careful answers. If you find someone whose Answer style matches
your taste, click on the avitar, look under Activity for
a list of Answers, and see if you find useful ones.

IMHO, it is a mistake to try to teach a course with only notes and no textbook. So I think you're on the right
track looking for texts to read along with lectures.
Wishing you success.