# What is the idea behind the $^2$ in the mean squared error?

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Mean Squared Error: $\operatorname{MSE}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n(\hat{Y_i} - Y_i)^2.$ <-- what is the purpose of the '$^2$'  in here?

Mean Absolute Error: $\mathrm{MAE} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \left| f_i-y_i\right| =\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n \left| e_i \right|$

Comment: To make the summand positive maybe?

Comment: Better behaved than the absolute value in terms of differentiability maybe?

Comment: @K.Rmth If you take the absolute value as with the 'Mean Absolute Error' you always a positive as well.

Comment: @Eckhard In which case can't you differentiate the the 'Mean Absolute Error'?

Comment: @Golan: it depends on you specific application but in general the absolute value function $x\mapsto|\cdot|$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: @Eckhard Why would I differentiate it at x = 0, instead of letting the value being undefined at that point?

Comment: Probably the same idea as in [Motivation behind standard deviation?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4787/motivation-behind-standard-deviation)

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the reasons pointed out to you by K.Rmth and Eckhard in their comments, consider that since $x^2 > |x|$ for $|x| > 1$ while $x^2 < |x|$ for $|x| < 1$ and thus the mean-square error penalizes large errors more that the mean absolute error does, but is more forgiving of small errors. Some people think that this emphasis on penalizing large errors more than small errors is a good thing; others don't.

Comment: Thanks! Could you give examples when 'penalizing large errors more than small errors' is a good thing and when it is a bad thing.

Comment: Nice explanation $;)$

Answer (score 0):

It is the same square as in the pythagorean theorem -- you are trying to find the Euclidean distance between the expected and the actual results.

Comment: I don't see the relation between this and the pythagorean theorem. Could you explain that, please?